# How does the Python tool Poetry know the path of a project's virtual environment?

Tags: python-poetry

**My question:** How does the Python tool Poetry know the path of the virtual environment of a project?

**Explanation:** When I run `poetry init` inside a directory, a new project is created. Then I run `poetry install` and a new virtual environment is created. HOWEVER, neither the path nor the hash of that virtual environment are stored in `pyproject.toml` or `poetry.lock` as I expected. How does Poetry then know the location of the virtual environment when I run `poetry env info -p`?

Besides wanting to know what is going on, I need to know this for 2 reasons:

- How can I move a directory with a Poetry project without breaking the link to its virtual environment?
- How to know which of Poetry's virtual environments are unused and can thus be deleted?

**Possible solution:** Looking into the source code of Poetry, it seemed to me that a file `envs.toml` may include a mapping from filesystem directories to virtual environment hashes, but on my Mac OS 11.1 I can't find such a file.

Comment: A related discussion happening now: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3459

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I dived deeper into the source code and I may have understood it now:

- The relevant code is at `poetry/utils/env.py` inside the method `EnvManager.generate_env_name(...)`
- The code deduces the location of the environment by using the project name from `pyproject.toml` and adding the hash of the parent directory of `pyproject.toml`

As a consequence:

- There is no simple way to delete environments which are not used anymore
- Also, if I want to move the directory of a poetry project, I would need to rename the virtual environment's folder and replace the hash correctly. This should work, but it would be preferable to just run `poetry install` again and create a new virtual environment

Comment: You can't rename (move) virtual environments, this doesn't work. You would need to do some search/replace inside some files as well. -- Indeed it might be a problem that some virtual environments are left abandoned long after the corresponding `pyproject.toml` has been moved or deleted. Thankfully it is super easy to recreate virtual environments from scratch in just one command. That is why it is quite safe to just delete lots of _poetry_ virtual environments even without being sure if they are still "_alive_".

Comment: You could use [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76913112/7057547) to generate the hashes for all your project directories and delete all environments that don't match.

Answer (score 1):

There's a poetry config variable that makes poetry install the virtual environment inside the project. Thus, if you delete the project directory, the venv will also be deleted. It also allows you to inspect what's in the venv, and delete/recreate the venv when needed.

From the cmd line:
`poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true`

Verify it's set:
`poetry config --list` (virtualenvs.in-project should be true)

Comment: I am not sure that the "venv will also be deleted" when the project directory is deleted. How would the venv (which is a folder somewhere else) know about the event that the project directory is deleted?

Comment: If you set the config var I mentioned, it will put the venv in the project dir. I think you may be misunderstanding something? Or I am?

Comment: Thanks for that clarification @echo, i missed that!